# problem treating a jsp like css in firefox, chrome

Tags: html, css, jsp, cross-browser

I am writing a web application for use by multiple organizations which requires custom styling depending on which customer is using my page (the page is "branded" for different companies).

Basically, I have a database which stores some information such as primary color, background color, and company logo image, all of which vary depending on who is using my site.

When someone comes to my site, I look up their styling information and put it in session scope as a parameter named "brand"

I have a jsp called brandCss.jsp which does things such as:

```css
#logo
{
   background-image: url( '${brand.logoImage}' );
}

body
{
   color: ${brand.primaryColor};
}
```

etc.

Then in the `<head>` tag of my page, I link to my JSP *as if it were a css file*:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/brandCss" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Using the spring framework, I map a request for /brandCss to my brandCss.jsp view, so that this request returns my JSP as a view.

This works great in IE--someone hits my page and my server code goes off and finds the branding (styling) information they need to see, then splats it into my JSP which is then treated as a css file.

However, in Firefox/Chrome, my brandCss.jsp stylesheet is not used--my page IS pulling down the jsp correctly, and it gets exactly the same information as IE, but for some reason the browser chooses to ignore the styling in it.

Anyone have any idea why this or how to make Firefox treat my JSP like css?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your page is setting the Content-Type to `text/css`. If the page isn't being served with the correct Content-Type, I would suspect Firefox would ignore it. This is easy to check with the help of something like the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (see the Net tab for the files that are requested).

I'm not exactly sure how you would go about setting the `Content-Type` in Spring, or from a Java web app, but that is what I would check first.

Comment: Just what I needed--I put <%@ page contentType="text/css" %> at the top of my jsp, and firefox/chrome recognized it as such immediately.  

Thanks a lot!